# SQLServerBulkCopy error handling

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, bcp

I'm investigating the SQLServerBulkCopy class to do a bulk insert into a database. Currently, I'm using JDBC and when I attempt to perform a bad insert, I can catch a BatchUpdateException to find out what row caused the problem.

How does SQLServerBulkCopy handle error rows, will I be able to do something similar?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-bulk-copy-with-the-jdbc-driver#BKMK_TransactionBulk)? The section "Performing a non-transacted bulk copy operation" has a pretty good description of the default behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for that. What still isn't clear to me though, in the non-transacted operation, if I have 10k rows is it doing 10k insert statements and committing after each one? As in, am I going to take a huge performance hit? Additionally, they're checking how many rows were added by querying the database - is that data not available in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"How does SQLServerBulkCopy handle error rows"*

If `.writeToServer` encounters an error it throws the exception that is returned from the server, e.g.,

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__#tmp______3213E83F719D9EEE'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.#tmp'. The duplicate key value is (1).

*"if I have 10k rows is it doing 10k insert statements and committing after each one?"*

No, it is sending an `INSERT BULK` statement and then streaming batches of rows to the server according to `SQLServerBulkCopyOptions#setBatchSize`. The default batch size is zero (0), meaning that it would effectively stream all 10K rows in one shot. For a batch size >0 it would stream that many rows and then repeat the `INSERT BULK` process until all rows have been copied.

If an error is encountered, [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-bulk-copy-with-the-jdbc-driver#BKMK_TransactionBulk) says:

> In this first example, the bulk copy operation is non-transacted. All batches copied up to the point of the error are committed; the batch containing the duplicate key is rolled back, and the bulk copy operation is halted before processing any other batches.

*"is [the number of rows actually copied] not available in java?"*

It appears not. `.writeToServer` returns `void`, and there does not appear to be a property of the `SQLServerBulkCopy` object to supply that information.

Comment: Thanks, that's a bummer but wasn't totally unexpected. Looks like we will have to choose between performance and logging. Thanks for confirming!